# C++, почему в консоль не выводится кирилица?

Tags: c++

Вроде вписал

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
wcout.imbue(locale(".1251"));
wcin.imbue(locale(".866"));
```

и все ровно какие то иероглифы выводит

мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include < fstream >
#include<locale.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    wcout.imbue(locale(".1251"));
    wcin.imbue(locale(".866"));

    char words \[150\];

    ifstream wordFile("cppstudio.txt");

    wordFile.getline(words, 150);
    
    cout << words;
}
```

Comment: А какова кодировка текста в файле?

Comment: а вообще можно написать программу с универсальной кодировкой ?

Comment: UTF 8 КОДИРОВКА В ФАЙЛЕ

Comment: Ну вот вам и ответ...

Comment: Потоки `cout` и `wcout` - несовместимы. Вы пользуетесь ими поочерёдно. `imbue` надо назначать на `cout`. И кодировка в `.cpp` тоже должна соответствовать тому, что хотите увидеть.

Comment: пора уже создавать метку "иероглифы" или "крякозяблы" и помечать все такие вопросы.